# Magento API list qty_increments by product

Tags: magento

Magento API has two calls for Stock: catalogInventoryStockItemList and catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate which uses the array catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity where a min_qty field can be updated.
I need to find the current value of that field for a ProductID before I can update it.

I can only use the standard API. (No PHP/SQL query.)